# Validating a OTP without storing it anywhere like database and Sessions

Tags: java, servlets

I have generated a eight digit random OTP and sent it to mail using servlet. I want to validate the OTP at the next page without storing it anywhere like database and session. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This technique is done using the following steps:**

- Create a cryptographic hash (HMAC) of the phone number, the generated OTP and the expiry timestamp combined.
- Append the expiry timestamp with the hash and Send the hash to the
  user as the response of the first request.
- Once the user gets the SMS, the user sends back the hash, the phone number and the OTP in the second request.
- The server verifies the OTP by hashing the phone number, OTP sent by the
  user, and the expiry timestamp that was appended with the hash, the user sent back. Using the same key and same algorithm.
- If the expiry timestamp is valid and still in the future. And the
  newly generated hash matches the one sent by the user. Then the OTP
  is authentic.

Comment: Eventhough the hash is stored in the session right? Can I do this without storing or else can i verify it at the same page?

Comment: How can you validate something without having something else to check against? If you can't store the password itself, store a hash which is irreversible.

Comment: Can I use JWT for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous answer implies storing data in the local storage, I would like to expose another solution that I am using in a project, based on magic links.

**TLDR**: Use a JWT. No storage but can't copy by hand.

##### Conditions

Can only work if the user is not asked to type the code by hand. Use an Html button in email or QRCode instead.

Depending on the situation that can be better UX than copying a code by hand.

##### Setup

- **Generate a JWT** containing the **user ID** for identification, [and sign the JWT with an **expiration date**](https://jwt.io/introduction#Payload).
- **Construct an URL** targeting your server or password reset page **with JWT in params**.
- Send the link to the user by email.
- When opening the link, the **user will make a request** with the JWT, you can then validate it and retrieve the user ID associated.

> Generated URL example: [https://your.app/password-reset?token={JWT}](https://your.app/password-reset?token=%7BJWT%7D)